# Laravel get records from model with certain data and relations

Tags: php, laravel

I have model Post:

```
protected $with = ['user']

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

When on controller I set only title and image:

```
$posts = Post::get(['title', 'image']);
```

Relation user return me null.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   User: {{ $post->user->name }} //null
@endforeach
```

Why? If I delete array from `get` method, then relation is working, If I set array, then relation user return me null. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

With `Post::get(['title', 'image']);` you are specifying that you only need these columns.

If you want to use that approach,

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->get(['title', 'image']);
```

Or you can include user not with `protected $with` property, but instead `protected $appends` to always add that in your model as a default field

```
// In Post Class:
protected $appends = "user";

// Then this should work
$posts = Post::get(['title', 'image', 'user']);
```